# Windows Update script

Tags: c#, windows, api, console, windows-update

I'm building a script that'll automatically look for, download and install updates using Windows Update.

I'm using this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using WUApiLib;
namespace update_script
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UpdatesAvailable();
        EnableUpdateServices();//enables everything windows need in order to make an update
        InstallUpdates(DownloadUpdates());
        Console.Read();
    }
    //this is my first try.. I can see the need for abstract classes here...
    //but at least it gives most people a good starting point.
    public static void InstalledUpdates()
    {
        UpdateSession UpdateSession = new UpdateSession();
        IUpdateSearcher UpdateSearchResult = UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher();
        UpdateSearchResult.Online = true;//checks for updates online
        ISearchResult SearchResults = UpdateSearchResult.Search("IsInstalled=1 AND IsHidden=0");
        //for the above search criteria refer to 
        //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386526(v=VS.85).aspx
        //Check the remakrs section

        foreach (IUpdate x in SearchResults.Updates)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Title);
        }
    }
    public static void UpdatesAvailable()
    {
        UpdateSession UpdateSession = new UpdateSession();
        IUpdateSearcher UpdateSearchResult = UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher();
        UpdateSearchResult.Online = true;//checks for updates online
        ISearchResult SearchResults = UpdateSearchResult.Search("IsInstalled=0 AND IsPresent=0");
        //for the above search criteria refer to 
        //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386526(v=VS.85).aspx
        //Check the remakrs section

        foreach (IUpdate x in SearchResults.Updates)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Title);
        }
    }
    public static UpdateCollection DownloadUpdates()
    {
        UpdateSession UpdateSession = new UpdateSession();
        IUpdateSearcher SearchUpdates = UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher();
        ISearchResult UpdateSearchResult = SearchUpdates.Search("IsInstalled=0 and IsPresent=0");
        UpdateCollection UpdateCollection = new UpdateCollection();
        //Accept Eula code for each update
        for (int i = 0; i < UpdateSearchResult.Updates.Count; i++)
        {
            IUpdate Updates = UpdateSearchResult.Updates[i];
            if (Updates.EulaAccepted == false)
            {
                try
                {
                    Updates.AcceptEula();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // Write a line to tell the user that an error occured with accepting this Eula
                    Console.WriteLine("Det oppsto en feil under akseptering av en Eula");
                }
            }
            UpdateCollection.Add(Updates);
        }
        //Accept Eula ends here
        //if it is zero i am not sure if it will trow an exception -- I havent tested it.

        UpdateCollection DownloadCollection = new UpdateCollection();
        UpdateDownloader Downloader = UpdateSession.CreateUpdateDownloader();

        for (int i = 0; i < UpdateCollection.Count; i++)
        {
            DownloadCollection.Add(UpdateCollection[i]);
        }

        // Define outside try-catch statement
        UpdateCollection InstallCollection = new UpdateCollection();
        try
        {
            Downloader.Updates = DownloadCollection;
            Console.WriteLine("Downloading Updates");
            IDownloadResult DownloadResult = Downloader.Download();
            for (int i = 0; i < UpdateCollection.Count; i++)
            {
                if (DownloadCollection[i].IsDownloaded)
                {
                    InstallCollection.Add(DownloadCollection[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Error occured, tell the user
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred while downloading the updates. Please reboot and try again.");
        }
        return InstallCollection;
    }
    public static void InstallUpdates(UpdateCollection DownloadedUpdates)
    {
        try
        {
            UpdateSession UpdateSession = new UpdateSession();
            UpdateInstaller InstallAgent = UpdateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller() as UpdateInstaller;
            InstallAgent.Updates = DownloadedUpdates;

            //Starts a synchronous installation of the updates.
            // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386491(v=VS.85).aspx#methods
            IInstallationResult InstallResult = InstallAgent.Install();

            Console.WriteLine("install block over");
            // Check if a reboot is required
            if (InstallAgent.RebootRequiredBeforeInstallation)
            {
                // Reboot
                Console.WriteLine("Reboot required");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // An error occured
            Console.WriteLine("An error occured while trying to install the updates. Try again but remember to run as administrator");
        }
    }
    public static void EnableUpdateServices()
    {
        IAutomaticUpdates updates = new AutomaticUpdates();
        if (!updates.ServiceEnabled)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not all updates services where enabled. Enabling Now" + updates.ServiceEnabled);
            updates.EnableService();
            Console.WriteLine("Service enable success");
        }


    }

}
}
```

I think it ran well the first time I ran it, but it threw an exception(s) the second time.

When running as administrator, this error occur:

[image]

Also, does a script like this require to be ran as admin?

Thanks for help on this!
Erik

Comment: Are you ensuring that there are updates? `0x80240024 WU_E_NO_UPDATE There are no updates`

Comment: @AlexK That's what struck me as it worked the first time. But why is it throwing an exception due to that? Why don't it just ignore it?

Comment: It looks like you try to download without checking that `UpdateCollection.Count` is `> 0` so your telling it to process a list of nothing; an exception seems reasonable here

Comment: @AlexK that definitely seems right. All of the methods are called right away within the Main() method, without any form of checking first. It basically tells the installer method to install nothing

Answer (score 0):

I use the following VBscript:

```
Set updateSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
Set updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateupdateSearcher()

WScript.Echo "Searching for updates..." & vbCRLF

Set searchResult = updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'")

If searchResult.Updates.Count > 0 Then

   WScript.Echo "List of applicable items on the machine:"

   For I = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count-1
       Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)
       WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> " & update.Title
   Next

   WScript.Echo vbCRLF & "Creating collection of updates to download:"

   Set updatesToDownload = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl")

   For I = 0 to searchResult.Updates.Count-1
       Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)
       WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> adding: " & update.Title 
       updatesToDownload.Add(update)
   Next

   WScript.Echo vbCRLF & "Downloading updates..."

   Set downloader = updateSession.CreateUpdateDownloader() 
   downloader.Updates = updatesToDownload
   downloader.Download()

   WScript.Echo  vbCRLF & "List of downloaded updates:"

   For I = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count-1
       Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)
       If update.IsDownloaded Then
          WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> " & update.Title 
       End If
   Next

   Set updatesToInstall = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl")

   WScript.Echo  vbCRLF & _
   "Creating collection of downloaded updates to install:" 

   For I = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count-1
       set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)
       If update.IsDownloaded = true Then
          WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> adding:  " & update.Title 
          updatesToInstall.Add(update)    
       End If
   Next

   WScript.Echo "Installing updates..."
   Set installer = updateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller()
   installer.Updates = updatesToInstall
   Set installationResult = installer.Install()

   'Output results of install
   WScript.Echo "Installation Result: " & installationResult.ResultCode 
   WScript.Echo "Reboot Required: " & installationResult.RebootRequired & vbCRLF 
   WScript.Echo "Listing of updates installed and individual installation results:" 

   For I = 0 to updatesToInstall.Count - 1
     WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> " & updatesToInstall.Item(i).Title & ": " & _ 
                  installationResult.GetUpdateResult(i).ResultCode         
   Next

   If installationResult.RebootRequired = True Then
      Reboot(".")
   End If

Else
    WScript.Echo "There are no applicable updates."
End If

WScript.Quit



Function Reboot(StrSrv)
   Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate,authenticationLevel=Pkt,(Shutdown)}!\\" & StrSrv & "\root\cimv2")
   Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem",,48)
   For Each objItem In colItems
        WScript.Echo objitem.Reboot
   Next
End Function
```

I use the following wrapper and have it scheduled to run once a week.  I've recently modified it for Windows 10, it now enables/disables the Windows Update service to restrict updates when the script is not running.  I like keeping logs of the updates in case issues develop.

```
D:
cd \WindowsUpdate

REM ************************************************************
REM ***     
REM *** Enable Windows Update Service
REM ***
REM ************************************************************

sc config wuauserv start=demand

REM ************************************************************
REM ***     
REM *** Generate Date/Time string for Log File
REM ***
REM ************************************************************

IF "%time:~0,1%" == " " (
   set time_stamp=[%date:~-4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%@0%time:~1,1%.%time:~3,2%.%time:~6,2%]
 ) ELSE (
   set time_stamp=[%date:~-4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%@%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2%.%time:~6,2%]
 )


REM ************************************************************
REM ***     
REM *** Handle any file settings
REM ***
REM ************************************************************

Set LOG=D:\WindowsUpdate\Logs\Update%time_stamp%.LOG 


REM ************************************************************
REM ***     
REM *** Execute the WindowsUpdate Check
REM ***
REM ************************************************************

cscript WindowsUpdate.vbs >%LOG%

REM ************************************************************
REM ***     
REM *** Disable Windows Update Service
REM ***
REM ************************************************************

sc config wuauserv start=disabled 

REM ************************************************************
REM ***     
REM *** End of script
REM ***
REM ************************************************************
```